# XERCESC 2.7 Memory Leak Problem

Tags: c++, xml, memory-leaks, xml-parsing, xerces

We are using XERCESC 2.7 unfortunately there is not too much about this topic on the web.

Question: What is the Workflow when parsing with Xerces? I will show the workflow i have and hopefully my memory leak will be spottet by somebody. Unfortunately i cannot install a memory debugger on the system due to restrictions.

Thanks OS

**Constructor:**

```
DOMBuilder * pDOMBuilder

pDOMBuilder =_pDOMImplementation->createDOMBuilder
(xercesc::DOMImplementationLS::MODE_SYNCHRONOUS, NULL);
        pDOMBuilder->setFeature(XMLUni::fgXercesUserAdoptsDOMDocument, true)
        pDOMBuilder->setFeature(xercesc::XMLUni::fgDOMNamespaces, true);
        pDOMBuilder->setFeature(xercesc::XMLUni::fgDOMValidation, true);
        pDOMBuilder->setFeature(xercesc::XMLUni::fgXercesSchema, true);
        pDOMBuilder->setFeature(xercesc::XMLUni::fgXercesSchemaFullChecking, true);
        pDOMBuilder->setFeature(xercesc::XMLUni::fgXercesValidationErrorAsFatal, true);
        pDOMBuilder->setFeature(xercesc::XMLUni::fgDOMWhitespaceInElementContent, false);
        pDOMBuilder->setFeature(xercesc::XMLUni::fgDOMDatatypeNormalization, true);
        m_pErrorHandler = new ErrorHandler();
        pDOMBuilder->setErrorHandler(m_pErrorHandler);
        pDOMBuilder->setEntityResolver(new EntityResolver(absolutePathToSchemas));
```

**Destructor:**

```
pDOMWriter->release();
```

**Usage of the Object:**

```
pDOMBuilder->resetDocumentPool();
pDOMBuilder->resetCachedGrammarPool(); 
m_ErrorHandler->reset();

xercesc::MemBufInputSource * pMemBufInputSource = new xercesc::MemBufInputSource((const XMLByte *)xmlStream, 
                                                                                         (unsigned int)strlen(xmlStream),
                                                                                         UnicodeString("xmlStream"));

xercesc::Wrapper4InputSource wrapper4InputSource(pMemBufInputSource);
xercesc::DOMDocument * resultDoc = m_DOMBuilder->parse(wrapper4InputSource);


resultDoc->release();
```

Answer (score 0):

Anything Xerces DOM object ptr acquired via a `createXXX` method should be released by calling its `release` method. You don't appear to be calling `pDOMBuilder->release ()`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i actually call ->release() but i reuse the pDOMBuilder multiple times before that. Is this an issue for the Memory? Should i re-initialize the DOMBuilder everytime before i need one ? I would assume that DOMBuilder will not keep more memory than its own structure. Maybe iam wrong, tell me. Thank you.

Comment: Short answer - don't know. Try releasing and creating a new on each time and see if that eliminates the memory leaks. There's some notes on Xerces C++ and memory usage on [their site](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/program-dom-3.html#DOMMemMgmt).